# What does 风轻发自然 mean here?

Tags: translation, phrase, phrase-meaning

At the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCA7iaBUD28), there is an introduction to the story of the singer, Lin Zijun. Here it is:

客家新流行乐创作歌手
2007［天黑黑］获苗栗客家音乐歌唱比赛    第三名
2006［匍背］获台湾创音乐大赛    客语首奖
2001全国丝竹比赛全国第一名

因为弱视的关系
小的时候只能听电视
或听鸟叫蟲鸣的声音
所以声音对资君来说    是全部也是生命

而她的音乐曲风轻发自然
让人忍不住细听着
她的生活故事

资君希望自己能够永远站在舞台上
用歌声抚慰所有的人
感动自己也感动别人
直到发禿齿搖的那一天

New popular Hakka music singer-songwriter
The 2007 song "Sky's so dark" (天黑黑) won the Miaoli Hakka music singing contest:    third place
The 2006 song "Support" (匍背) won the Taiwan big composition contest    Hakka-language first prize
In 2001 she won national first place in the national string-and-woodwind music contest

Because of amblyopia,
When she was young, she could only listen to TV
Or listen to the sounds of birds and insects
So sounds for Zijun    are everything and are her life

And the 风轻发自然 (??) in her songs and music
Make people unable to avoid carefully listening
To her life story

Zijun hopes she can forever stand on the stage
And comfort all people with her singing voice
Moving herself and moving others
Till the day her hair is stripped out and her teeth shake

What does the phrase "风轻发自然", which I failed to translate, mean here?

Comment: 曲风/轻发自然. not "风轻发自然"

Comment: @fefe OK, so qǔfēng means "style", which with "yīnyuè" makes a "musical style", but what is "qīng fā"? Or was it "qīng fà" with the hair character? Can't remember…

Comment: 轻: 轻松，轻快; 发: 抒发;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video, it reads

> 而她的音樂曲風輕鬆自然

which would be

> 而她的音乐曲风轻松自然

in simplified Chinese.

It seems you have mistaken 鬆 for 髮.

This line would translate to "Her musical style is relaxed and natural".

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be 轻快  instead of 轻发

轻快自然 (lively and natural) make more sense than 轻发自然 (come out lightly and nature)

Beside, '轻发' could mean  '轻举妄动' (act rashly)

> [轻发则多败](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%85%8E%E9%87%8D%E5%88%99%E5%BF%85%E6%88%90%EF%BC%8C%E8%BD%BB%E5%8F%91%E5%88%99%E5%A4%9A%E8%B4%A5)
>
> *轻发：轻举妄动*

I suspect the author thought '轻发'(lightly come out) and '轻快'(lively) mean the same